# Query about header image. Is the HTML and CSS correct/most efficent way of doing this?

Tags: html, css, header

This is how my site looks so far (Note: I'm kinda trying to teach myself how to do the HTML for this site right now.  I'll worry about the design later.  I know thats now how one should go about designing a site.  But whatever)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPXKZ.jpg

For the header, is this HTML correct/efficient?  If not, what is the correct/efficient way to achieve this effect for the header?  The header is all one image.

Thanks for any help in advance!

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>CogRobot Studios</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="stylesheets/screen.css" />
    <!--[if IE]>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/cogrobot.css" />
  </head> 

  <body>

    <div id="wrap" class="container">
     <div id="bigheader"> </div>
    <div id="header" class="rounded-corners column span-24 last"></div>

    <div id="content" class="column span-15 colborder">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis risus eu nisi feugiat tincidunt sed vel eros. Maecenas a bibendum tellus. Nunc eu risus at tortor placerat mollis vel et lacus. Ut non massa odio, et commodo sapien. Aliquam erat volutpat. Morbi sed sem at nunc congue venenatis a blandit nisi. Donec eget tortor nisl, vel laoreet nisi. Donec vel posuere ligula. Nullam mi risus, porta lacinia ullamcorper ut, mollis eget arcu. Nam justo dui, dignissim eu dapibus at, placerat vulputate ante. Suspendisse justo tortor, gravida quis scelerisque in, fringilla non eros. 
      </p>

      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis risus eu nisi feugiat tincidunt sed vel eros. Maecenas a bibendum tellus. Nunc eu risus at tortor placerat mollis vel et lacus. Ut non massa odio, et commodo sapien. Aliquam erat volutpat. Morbi sed sem at nunc congue venenatis a blandit nisi. Donec eget tortor nisl, vel laoreet nisi. Donec vel posuere ligula. Nullam mi risus, porta lacinia ullamcorper ut, mollis eget arcu. Nam justo dui, dignissim eu dapibus at, placerat vulputate ante. Suspendisse justo tortor, gravida quis scelerisque in, fringilla non eros. 
      </p>

      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis risus eu nisi feugiat tincidunt sed vel eros. Maecenas a bibendum tellus. Nunc eu risus at tortor placerat mollis vel et lacus. Ut non massa odio, et commodo sapien. Aliquam erat volutpat. Morbi sed sem at nunc congue venenatis a blandit nisi. Donec eget tortor nisl, vel laoreet nisi. Donec vel posuere ligula. Nullam mi risus, porta lacinia ullamcorper ut, mollis eget arcu. Nam justo dui, dignissim eu dapibus at, placerat vulputate ante. Suspendisse justo tortor, gravida quis scelerisque in, fringilla non eros. 
      </p>

      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis risus eu nisi feugiat tincidunt sed vel eros. Maecenas a bibendum tellus. Nunc eu risus at tortor placerat mollis vel et lacus. Ut non massa odio, et commodo sapien. Aliquam erat volutpat. Morbi sed sem at nunc congue venenatis a blandit nisi. Donec eget tortor nisl, vel laoreet nisi. Donec vel posuere ligula. Nullam mi risus, porta lacinia ullamcorper ut, mollis eget arcu. Nam justo dui, dignissim eu dapibus at, placerat vulputate ante. Suspendisse justo tortor, gravida quis scelerisque in, fringilla non eros. 
      </p>

    </div>

    <div id="sidebar" class="column span-7 last">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis risus eu nisi feugiat tincidunt sed vel eros. Maecenas a bibendum tellus. Nunc eu risus at tortor placerat mollis vel et lacus. Ut non massa odio, et commodo sapien. Aliquam erat volutpat. Morbi sed sem at nunc congue venenatis a blandit nisi. 
      </p>

      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis risus eu nisi feugiat tincidunt sed vel eros. Maecenas a bibendum tellus. Nunc eu risus at tortor placerat mollis vel et lacus. Ut non massa odio, et commodo sapien. Aliquam erat volutpat. Morbi sed sem at nunc congue venenatis a blandit nisi. 
      </p>

    </div>

    <div class="rounded-cornersbottom" id="footer">
      &copy; 2005, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      <br />
      All trademarks and registered trademarks appearing on 
      this site are the property of their respective owners.
    </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#wrap{
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
}

body { 
  background:   background: url("../images/header.png");
  font-family:      Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size:        small;
  margin:           0px;

}

p, ul, li, h1, h2, h3, h4 {
    margin: 0;
}

h3 {
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#bigheader{
      background: url("../images/gearheader2.png") no-repeat;
      min-height: 347px;
      min-width: 1062px;
      top: -115px;
      right: 0px;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: -99;
      margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {

  width:            950px;
  height:           177px;
}

#content{
 background:       #dbdbdb;
 font-size:        105%;
 padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
 margin: 0;
 width: 590px;

}

#sidebar {
  float: right;
  background:       #dbdbdb;
  font-size:        105%;
 padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;

  margin: 0;

}

#footer {
  background-color: #838383;
  color:            #c8c8c8;
  text-align:       center;

  font-size:        90%;
  clear:            left;
}

h1 {
  font-size:        120%;
  color:            #954b4b;
}

h2 { 
    font-size: 110%; 
}

.slogan { 
    color: #954b4b; 
}

.beanheading {
  text-align:       center;
  line-height:      1.8em;
}

a:link {
  color:            #b76666;
  text-decoration:  none;
  border-bottom:    thin dotted #b76666;
}
a:visited {
  color:            #675c47;
  text-decoration:  none;
  border-bottom:    thin dotted #675c47;
}

.rounded-corners {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 20px;

    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 20px;

    -khtml-border-radius: 20px; 
}

.rounded-cornersbottom {
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 20px;

    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;

    -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Comment: If you are using absolute positioning and negative z-indices on a header you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: So, what is the RIGHT way of achieving the desired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i have made the some changes in your HTML due to some errors so now its working fine.

And about the header part i have made few changes as mentioned below :-

**#bigheader** (i have applied here small circles images rather than your heavy large header image placed in header with positing).

**#header** (i have made the header completely css based use of border-radius & background color.)

You can see your updated HTML here :-
http://jsfiddle.net/KXGfj/23/

Comment: Thanks!  But would you be able to explain the changes you made?  I'd like to know so I know for future projects.

Comment: Hi justin where i have made the changes in css im mentioning  those css id's :- #wrap , #bigheader, #header, #content, #sidebar, #footer.
So once you will compare my CSS with your's CSS so you will get it what changes i have made it.....regards

Answer (score 0):

Hey you have used one of the css frameworks,. anyways yes i don't know if this is correct of an efficient way but i usually encapsulate the sub header div inside header div..

in your case something like.:
{(bigheader) {(header)}}

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Blueprint.css.  Well, I did as you said and it looks like it didn't break.  Although I still have to use absolute positioning to keep it in the center, even though one commenter said its wrong.